# Python equivalent for nested c++ style for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

In c++

```
for (auto i = min; i < sqrt_max; i++ ) {
    for (auto  j = i; i*j <= sqrt_max; j++) {
```

I am trying to do the exact same thing in python

```
for i in enumerate(range(min, sqrt_max  + 1)):
    for j in enumerate(range(min, i * j < sqrt_max + 1)):
```

I get `undefined name j`

Comment: You are using `j` in your for expression. It's only defined inside the loop.

Comment: You probably don't need `enumerate` here. You want to iterate over `range` objects directly, not enumerated `range` objects.

Comment: As a general guide, don't try to write C++ in python, write python in python.   If you don't change your style when you switch to another language you will never really get under its skin.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use `enumerate(..)` in both your loops. `enumerate` takes something that returns a pair of `index, element` for each `element` in its argument.
2. You can not use `j` the way you do because it is defined only within the for-loop body.

What you want is something like below:

```
for i in range(min, sqrt_max):  # i will not take the value of sqrt_max.
    for j in range(i, 1 + sqrt_max//i):  # i is defined here within range, but j is not.
        ...
```